# sprite Kit save highest score

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I build a game using Sprite Kit(with swift xCode 6 beta 4) and I need to keep the highest score that the player reached(so just an one Int). I know there is a way to do it using NSCoding, I googled it and found only Objective-C tutorials/guides which I can't use because I don't know objective-c at all, and maybe there are better ways that came in late versions of xCode. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest beta when they come out. You're only going to be missing out on fixes and improvements by using old betas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save the highest score in [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/). It is used to persist small amount of data and really easy to use.You can save the highest score like

```
// To save highest score
var highestScore:Int = 20
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highestScore, forKey:"HighestScore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

// To get the saved score
var savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighestScore") as Int
println(savedScore)
```

`NSUserDefaults` is mainly used for persisting these kind of data like high-score of user.

Comment: Could rather than should. You could store it anywhere. As a file. In a database. On a server. It's really unrelated to using spritekit.

Comment: @uchuugaka yes you can save anywhere but it is very convenient to save in `NSUserDefaults`.Apple has provided `NSUserDefaults` to store these kinds of things.It provides more benefits than file.You can use app groups to share user defaults data between apps and have many other benefits.

Comment: User defaults is for storing user preferences. It's not intended as a general data storage.

Comment: @codester How would you display the savedScore if you've yet to get a score to put in highest score. How would you get it to display 0 if there isn't anything saved in the user defaults yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSCoding
but can also use NSUserDefaults (but it can be easily edited by the user so not reccommended, mainly used for storing user preferences etc but it will work)
Hope this helps