# Integer changes to 0 after init

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using NSUserDefaults ([StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227921/sprite-kit-save-highest-score)) to save a high score in an iOS Swift (Sprite Kit) game.

It's declared like this:

```
var savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("hiScore") as! Int
```

This returns for example '2' as high score.

If the high score gets beaten I do this:

```
if self.score > self.savedScore {

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.score, forKey:"hiScore")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            println("Synced")
        }
```

However, the problem is that `self.savedScore` becomes `0` after the initial value of `2`, causing the high score to get saved after every game, since every possible score is higher than the `0`.

Additional code can be provided if needed for this question.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "after the initial value". Exactly when and where does it become 0

Comment: why are you not using `integerForKey` and `setInteger` instead of Object? And why `"hiScore"` instead of `"highScore"`? And have you checked that it "returns for example '2' as high score"?

Comment: Looks like you're re-declaring savedScore locally and thus setting the local version as opposed to self.savedScore.

Comment: Add property observers to `savedScore`, say, to print its value before (`willSet` property observer) and after (`didSet` property observer) it's set, then put breakpoints on the `println()` lines. That way you'll be able to figure out exactly when (and why) `savedScore` is being reset to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get score from NSUserDefaults and save it in new variable:

```
var savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("hiScore")
```

saveScore is the variable you created every time this code is called.
After that you compare score to self.savedScore, which is different than savedScore:

```
if self.score > self.savedScore { ... }
```

replace the first line where you get the save score with:

```
self.savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("hiScore")
```

and you should use integerForKey to get the data and when you save it use setInteger instead of setObject