# How to make highscore update instantly in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

currently I'm working on a game project and I've run into an issue where the game's highscore doesn't update unless I quit the app (completely close) and run the game again. In terms of code I've got this written down.

```
var data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
//this is when the level is over and the highscore is saved
if score > level1HS{
    data.setInteger(score, forKey: "level1HS")
        data.synchronize()
    }

//and this is in the main menu where the highscore is shown
level1text.text = "\(String(level1HS))"
```

I've also tried replacing the `level1text.text = "\(String(level1HS)"` with this `level1text.text = "\(level1HS)"`

Can somebody please help me find a way to have the game update the highscore as soon as it is achieved ? Thank you!

Comment: Where is this code being called?  By the looks of things the code is fine, it just isn't being called often enough.  Make sure you call it when you want the score to update.  If you want this to be instantaneous, one way is to use a timer but I'd have to see the rest of the code to determine the best way forward.

Comment: @MattKelly so the first line of code is a universal variable. The third to fifth line of code is being called at the end of the level when the game is over. The last line of code is called in the main menu before the level is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you're trying to update the high score, you'll need to listen to the notification for when `StandardUserDefaults()` gets updated. It would look like this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
center.addObserverForName(NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) -> Void in
let newScore = defaults.objectForKey("level1HS")
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, Xcode tells me to change `let newScore = defaults.objectForKey("level1HS")` to `let newScore:AnyObject? = defaults.objectForKey("level1HS")` and after I do that it doesn't let me put it as text

Comment: well, I've managed to put it in a text, however it still doesn't give me what i need

Comment: Try if let score = defaults.objectForKey("level1HS") as? String {...} unless it's an integer than use that instead

Comment: alright it worked! however now in the app it says Optional(3) if the highscore is 3. how do I remove the optional part? Also is the highscore is nil it says nil, how do I replace that?

Comment: When you're printing you need to check if the variable is nil, and if it's not then it's safe to unwrap it with the ! operator. As for replacing the nil value, since you'll be checking to unwrap it, I'd it is nil you can print assign whatever else you want.

Comment: I'm trying to teach you not just give you answers. The same way you check unwrapped your defaults is how you would do the same thing for checking if what's assigned is nil

Comment: please, I need you to help me not teach me. PLEASE PLEASE!! how do I do this?

Comment: If let score = defaults.objectForKey("level1HS") as? String { level1text.text = score!} else {level1text.text = 0} sorry the code isn't formatted well I'm on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the following?

```
var level1HS = 10
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highestScore, forKey:"level1HS")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Your problem is probably that you are not using the .synchronize() method.
Also, check out this question:
[SpriteKit High Score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227921/sprite-kit-save-highest-score)

Comment: i did use `.synchronize()` however the problem still persists